# pandas - reading dynamically named file within a .zip

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a new dataframe in pandas as below:

`df = pd.read_excel(zipfile.open('zipfilename 2017-06-28.xlsx'), header=1, names=cols`)

The single .xlsx within the .zip is dynamically named (so changes based on the date).

This means I need to change the name of the .xlsx in my code each time I open the .zip to account for the dynamically named .xlsx.

Is there a way to make pandas read the file within the .zip, regardless of the name of the file? Or to return the name of the .xlsx within the line of code somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Read your file using,

`df = pd.read_excel('zipfilename 2017-06-28.xlsx',compression='zip', header=1, names=cols)`